# AWS SSL configuration using Gandi.net SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
```

after the successful creation of ngnix.key and ngnix.crt

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name your_domain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

sudo service nginx restart
```

I have generated .crt file and .key file but after above process the certificate is invalid on domain please help to configure stepwise in aws ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to generate the .key and .crt files and then the SSL certificate key and .crt file concat in single file and give that file path to nginx configuration file. 
https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2012/gandi-standard-ssl-certificate-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

Nginx uses 'Host' header for server_name matching. default_server looks to be missing from your snippet.

```
server {
 server_name _yourdomain.com;
 listen 80 default_server ipv6only=on;
 listen 443 ssl default_server;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
 return 404; # or whatever
 }
```